# Forward request to another port based on client IP

Tags: web-services, .net-core, iis

I have a .NET webservice running some code on an internal network that does analysis on data when an API call is made from a client device. This webservice is running on a Windows VM using IIS. We are testing some new analysis, but do not want to update the client application that makes the call to the webservice.

My plan is to stand a second webservice up on another port, but on the same VM. We want to test this only on a small number of clients. Is it possible for me to configure IIS so that if a request comes from a specific IP (or computer name) it forwards the request to the "TestService" running on a different port, but all other clients will continue to have their requests go to the existing, released service?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing Once you set up a reverse proxy, traffic can be manipulated anyway you want (of course within the limits of the rule system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a websiteA in IIS and use it as a proxy to forward API requests, then configure IIS forwarding, please make sure the following IIS components are installed on your server:

- Application Request Routing
- URL Rewrite

Assuming you create websiteB as a second web service on another port:

1. Please double-click URL Rewrite in websiteA and select Add Rule(s).
2. In the Add Rule dialog, select Reverse Proxy.
3. In the opened "Add Reverse Proxy Rule" dialog box, enter the host name or IP address (including port number) of websiteB,
4. Then a rewrite rule will be generated after confirmation, which can be modified according to your actual situation.
5. In IIS Manager, select the server node, double-click the Application Request Routing module, select Server Proxy Setting...and check Enable Proxy.

All client requests to access websiteA will forwarded to websiteB, and the content of websiteB is returned to the client.